# Simulate Multiple Monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to find out if there is a product out there to simulate Multiple Monitors on one large monitor/tv?  So take a screen and turn it into something like below...

```
--------------------------------
|               |              |
|               |              |
|               |              |
|               |              |
--------------------------------
|               |              |
|               |              |
|               |              |
|               |              |
--------------------------------
```

Something like this...even though in reality it's a single screen.  A software solution is perfectly fine as long as it functions like the built in Windows 8 functionality (Start screen only consumes the screen it was started on/etc).

If anyone is curious as to the reason.  I'm looking to get a treadmill desk since I'm a developer and don't like being sedentary all day.  So the two options that I see are having 4 monitors and mirroring them (I don't want to have to worry about forgetting to move the window that I need) or getting a large monitor/tv and putting it on an arm that I can simply swivel into place.

*There are dual-monitor swivel mounts, but they are EXTREMELY pricey and the ones I've found don't appear to have the range of motion that I'm anticipating needing.*

**EDIT:**  I found [this](http://ow.ly/gHhVs)... but I can't find the answer to the start menu question (I've sent the company a message on facebook).  Hoping I hear good news as this appears to offer many of the features I'm wanting.  So Fingers crossed there.

Comment: If this is for a single computer, couldn't you use use Start8 (so forgetting the start screen entirely) and just move the windows into each quadrant you want them in on the big monitor?

Comment: I actually like the new start menu and think that most people that are against it...haven't given it a shot and/or haven't discovered the power of search in 8.  So while this might be an option, it's not one I'm willing to consider. (and yes I do get that some people may just really not like it)

Comment: Yeah I see - so effectively you are simulating four monitors so a quarter of the screen can be taken up by the tiles.  There may be some software around that will force Windows 8 to only use a portion of the screen for Start, which would also achieve what you want without the simulation.  But I don't know any :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to make windows think I had two monitors.

I have solved my own problem by:

1. Right click on the desktop, click 'Screen Resolution'
2. Click 'Detect' on the next screen
3. Click 'Another display not detected' and under the multiple displays option select 'Try to connect anyway on: VGA'
4. Click 'Apply'
5. You can now enable your desktop to be extended as if you have a second screen plugged into your computer.

To view the second screen. This can be done via LogMeIn or TeamViewer on iOS, Android, Windows, Mac and I believe Linux:

I used TeamViewer as I already use it, so already have it installed

1. Opened TeamViewer on iPad
2. Connect to the computer setup previously
3. Using a 'Monitor' button at the bottom, select and show screen number 2.
4. iPad now shows screen 2 from PC.

Comment: +1 I haven't tested it yet but seems very simple

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) would provide the features you're looking for.

> Monitor splitting allows you to divide your monitor into multiple "virtual" monitors with their own Taskbars, Wallpapers, and Screen Savers.

My affiliation to DF: Satisfied user. :)