# Split one physical monitor in multiple screens that are detected by Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a  super ultra wide screen (32:9) and I want Windows to think that I have multiple physical screens.

Currently I use Display Fusion and so far it's a good solution.

But I want Windows to think I have multiple screens, so I can set up for example a game in fullscreen mode and chose on which screen I want it to appear (but still only the one physical screen is connected).

Is there any software or maybe also hardware that tricks windows that I got multiple screens?

One thing that is working: The screen got picture by picture if I connect two display cables. That's kind of the solution, but it splits the monitor in half. I want to split it in 3 screens with my own desired resolutions.

I found this post already, but they won't solve my "problem":

[Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor/796884?newreg=9fe6b6271e134c9ca407594dd14541c3)

[Simulate Multiple Monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/531803/simulate-multiple-monitors)